# Add custom classes to pre-trained data-set

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, pre-trained-model

I use the already trained(pre-trained) data-set for object detection using yolo+tensorflow. 
My inference results are great but now I want to "add" a new class to pre-trained data-set.
There are 80 classes in pre-trained data-set how can I add my custom classes and made it 81 or 82 in total?
Inference git-hub  "https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow".

Comment: For the new classes, you need to add the relevant data and train the model again. You can see how to create your own data set for tensorflow object detection api in the link - https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of transfer learning, pre-trained weights on famous datasets like 'Imagenet', 'fashion-mnist' etc are used. These datasets have defined number of classes and labels which may or may not be same as our dataset. The best practice is to add layers above the output layer of the pre-trained model output. For example in keras:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications import mobilenet
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
output = mobilenet(include_top=False)
flatten = Flatten()(output)
predictions = Dense(number_of_classes, activation='softmax')(layer)
```

In this case you need to train(or better call it fine tune) the model using your dataset. The mobilenet network will use pretrained weights and the last  layer will be only trained as per your dataset with the your defined number of classes.

You may also use:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications import mobilenet
preds = mobilenet(include_top=Flase, classes=number_of_classes, weights='imagenet')
```

for more information you can refer: [keras-applications](https://keras.io/applications/) 
and these [blog1](https://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/), [blog2](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/machine-learning/transfer-learning/transfer-learning-intro/tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please, can you tell me how to "add" a custom object for yolo-v2 or yolo-v3?

Comment: Can anyone suggest any other way to add classes to a pre-trained data-set??

Answer (score 0):

If you have already trained your model for 80 classes and need to add another class, then it would be better to re-train the model starting from previously saved checkpoints.(The network architecture should be designed for the total number of classes since the beginning cause at the output layer you will have neurons equal to the number of classes, if that is not the case you cannot add other class to the data as network has not been designed for it.) This will make use of initial training done on previous classes. The data that you are using for re-training, should now contain all the classes (including all the previous class and the new classes that you want to add). It's similar to initializing the weights from last trained checkpoint(on 80 classes) and then again train using more data (including all the classes 80 + more that you want to add) allowing back propagation through all the layers.